# ProgressDialog does not always show up

Tags: android

My application works as a BluetoothServer, almost the same as the `BluetoothChat example`. I'm facing a strange problem. Inside my run-method where I start reading input from the bluetoothSocket, I want to post a message to a handler. This handler is in a seperate class, to avoid possible memory leaks.

```
public void run() {
    Log.i("", "BEGIN ReadInputThread");
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesread;

    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.obj = "0";
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
    ...... snip .....
```

When I receive the String "0", in my handler, I want to show a progressDialog that informing the user that the application has an incoming file. In my handler, this is how I deal with it:

```
public class MessageHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) c.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        String message = (String) m.obj;

        //Getting files
        if (message.equals("0")) {

            folder.appendToLogFile(new Date().toString(), "Incoming File From: " + deviceName); 
            v.vibrate(1500);
            pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Retrieving file from " + deviceName);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }
}
```

The first time, when I have my Activity open, which will start this Thread, the progressDialog will show. After the transfer has finished, I navigate to a new Activity, and then returning to the previous Activity. When I now try to transfer a file, it will succeed, but no ProgressDialog is shown on the screen.

I did some checks just to figure out if the ProgressDialog is "visible" by adding these two lines under the `pd.show() statement`

```
if(pd.isShowing())
    Log.w("Handler: ", "inside the handler, and the progressdialog is showing");
```

And this also appears in LogCat, even if the ProgressDialog is not showing!

Can anybody give me a hint, or a solution to this frustration issue?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Just to clarify a bit**

My ProgressDialog is created in a class which not extends Activity, it doesn't extend any classes. 
The first thing I do, is to post a 0 to my handler, in the start of my `run() method`. When I know that I have received the last byte-packet from the socket, I send another message to the handler:

```
if(lastPacket) {
    msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.obj = "1";  
    handler.sendMessage(msg);                                                    
}
```

And in my Handler:

```
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {

        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) c.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        String message = (String) m.obj;

        //Getting files
        if (message.equals("0")) {

            folder.appendToLogFile(new Date().toString(), "Incoming File From: " + deviceName); 
            v.vibrate(1500);
            pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Retrieving file from " + deviceName);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
            if(pd.isShowing())
                Log.w("Handler: ", "inside the handler, and the progressdialog is showing");


        }

        //File complete 
        if(message.equals("1")) {

            Toast.makeText(c, "File Received from: " + deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            folder.appendToLogFile(new Date().toString(), "File Received"); 
            pd.setMessage(c.getResources().getString(R.string.createCase));

            GenerateCase caseGenerator = new GenerateCase(c, pd, lastCases, nextPCN);
            caseGenerator.execute("");
        }
    }
```

as you can see, I pass the ProgressDialog into the AsyncTask. In my `onPostExecute` method, I dismiss this `ProgressDialog`

### Solution

If someone is curious. I got confused with the threads. When I left my Activity, I forgot to kill my running thread, which would cause the ProgressDialog to start in a different thread when I resumed my activity.

Comment: Before navigate to a new Activity, close your pm.dismiss() in onPause Method

Answer (score 0):

Close your progress dialog via broadcast `Intent`;

```
onPostExecute(){
sendBroadcastIntent(new Intent("ACTION_CLOSE_DIALOG"):
}

BroadCastReceiver receiver = new BroadCastReceiver(){
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               if(pd.isShowing()){  
                pd.dismiss();
               }else{
                    pd.show()
                }
             }
        }
```

call Broadcast here:

```
pd.show();// call broadcast instead pd.show() use sendBroadcastIntent(new Intent("ACTION_CLOSE_DIALOG")
```

Comment: This works only the first time. When I change activity, and going back to the previous activity, the progressdialog does not show up.